# How to check an encrypted (Veracrypt) external (USB) disk that has a BTRFS file system?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, btrfs, veracrypt

I want to test if physical errors of the disk, of it that is not possible, file system errors of the disk. The disk is a typical USB external drive. The disk (not by partition-level, but the whole disk itself) is encrypted using VeraCrypt. The partition I stored the files is using Btrfs. What is the way?

---

Here are the things I have tried on my own:

First, the web search result said `badblocks` but other result said that it is an obsolete tool now. And when I ran it, it asked for read-only something, and that made me think that it may destruct existing files, so I cancelled it.

Then, I tried to use the "Check filesystem" context menu on the volume of the VeraCrypt. But it showed an "fsck" window saying "If you wish to check the consistency of a BTRFS filesystem or repair a damaged filesystem, see btrfs(8) subcommand 'check'" and exited.

[image]

I opened a Terminal and tried to execute `btrfs check` but "sudo btrfs check  (the device name)" failed with "no valid btrfs found on /dev/sdd" (probably because the whole disk is encrypted") and "sudo btrfs check (the decrypted directory)" failed with "not a regular file or block device".

[image]

---

PS: Thanks to the accepted answer, I got the correct device name. I am adding the following for future people who encounter the same problem. The comment I used was `sudo btrfs --force --check-data-csum -p /dev/mapper/veracrypt1`. I added `--check-data-csum`, because without it, it only checked the disk for the metadata checksum, not the actual files, so I had to run the test again (doing all the previous checks again). `-p` seems to be a nice option because it displays how many items have been checked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the disk for errors, you can use [SMART](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.):

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdd
```

or if you want GUI you can use GNOME Disks and the *SMART Data & Self-Test* menu option. (Not all external drives support SMART, this might not work for you.)

To check the filesystem, you can't use `/dev/sdd` because it holds the encrypted data, not the "readable" btrfs filesystem. Use `lsblk` to get name of the dm-crypt device which is used to access the cleartext data (it will probably be `/dev/mapper/veracrypt1`) and run the filesystem check on it:

```
btrfs check /dev/mapper/veracrypt1
```

Comment: It seems `smartctrl` is not supported for my Seagate. I ran the comment and it said "Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command".

`/dev/mapper/veracrypt1` worked. It warned about the partition being mounted, but I don't know of a way to unmount the drive without also removing decryption in VeraCrypt's GUI, so I continued with the `--force` argument.

Comment: @DamnVegetables, this blog site, says to do: sudo veracrypt -p secretpassword -k "" --protect-hidden=no /path/to/disk --filesystem=none; then: veracrypt -l, to get location of semi-mounted drive, http://john.wesorick.com/2012/03/running-fsck-on-truecrypt-volume.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try a simple cat

```
sudo cat /dev/sdd > /dev/null
```

That will go through the raw device and should report if there are physical-level errors.

Answer (score 0):

`badblocks` should be safe, after all, it asks only for **read only** access by default (unless you use the `-w` option). Run it as `badblocks -s -v /dev/sdd`. Though a better way (unless the disk is a SDD) is `smartctl -t long /dev/sdd`, then use `smartctl -a /dev/sdd` to monitor the progress (it will take some time) and to see the number of bad (i. e. reallocated) blocks.